# Android разбить большой текст на страницы (быстрое решение)

Tags: java, android, pagination

Доброго дня всем!
У меня есть необходимость отображения больших текстовых файлов в приложении. Текст нужно отображать без скролла, листанием как в электронных книгах. Я могу разбить длинный текст на страницы, но это занимает у меня слишком много времени. Например - следующий код обрабатывает 1.4 MB текста в течение примерно 10-15 секунд.

```
 public void split(TextPaint textPaint, String filepath,Context context) {
        int pages = 0;
        File file = new File(filepath);
        char[] bufferChar = new char[1024]; //Чтобы не возникло out of memory, будем считывать файл небольшими кусками
        String uncompletedtext="";
        //Определяем максимальное количество линий на страницу
        int maxLinesOnpage = 0;
        StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(
                context.getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum),
                textPaint,
                pageWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                lineSpacingMultiplier,
                lineSpacingExtra,
                false
        );
        int startLineTop = staticLayout.getLineTop(0);
        int endLine = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(startLineTop + pageHeight);
        int endLineBottom = staticLayout.getLineBottom(endLine);
        if (endLineBottom > startLineTop + pageHeight) {
            maxLinesOnpage = endLine - 1;
        } else {
            maxLinesOnpage = endLine;

        }

// Поехала пагинация        
try {
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while (buffer.read(bufferChar)>=0) {
                uncompletedtext += new String(bufferChar);
                boolean allcomplete = false;


                    staticLayout = new StaticLayout(
                            uncompletedtext,
                            textPaint,
                            pageWidth,
                            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                            lineSpacingMultiplier,
                            lineSpacingExtra,
                            false
                    );
                    staticLayout.getLineCount();
                    int curTextPages= (int) Math.floor(staticLayout.getLineCount() / maxLinesOnpage);
                    uncompletedtext=uncompletedtext.substring(staticLayout.getLineEnd(curTextPages));
                    pages+=curTextPages;
                    Log.e("PAGES","" + pages);



            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("FILE READED FULLY!!", "READ COMPLETE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");




    }
```

Это очень долго. Я не могу понять, как приложения, такие как FBReader и СoolReader работают с большими файлами (более 9 МБ) мгновенно.
Я видел исходники приложений, но эти исходники реально очень большие, чтобы разобраться в такой небольшой проблеме.
Мне очень нужна помощь и советы. Благодарю.

Comment: Может, не надо разбивать сразу весь файл? Достаточно получить следующие 2 страницы (ну или 10 страниц, чтобы поддерживать прокрутку "большими шагами" по нескольку страниц за раз), а при любой смене страницы проверять, сколько осталось разбитых страниц, и доразбивать до нужного количества.
Еще вариант - после разбиения первых 10 страниц позволять пользователю работать с ними, как будто всё уже готово, а в фоновом потоке продолжать разбивать остальное.

Comment: Думал уже над подобным решением (про фоновое вычисление страниц). В принципе оно годное, как крайний вариант. Но у этого варианта есть одна нехорошая сторона - пока весть текст не обсчитается - будет даже неизвестно, сколько страниц всего в книге. Меня поражает, как с этим справляется FBReader. Там просто магия какая-то. Тем не менее, если с первой страницы перескочить на какую-нибудь тысячную, то FB все-таки подтормаживает и скрипит. Но как они все-таки умудряются хотябы посчитать общее количество страниц так быстро?

Comment: Количество символов в файле разделить на среднее число символов на 1 странице = примерное число страниц. Кроме того, можно из размера попробовать: если на странице помещается 200 байт текста, то файл в килобайт будет содержать 5 страниц. Размер страницы мы получим почти сразу после начала разбиения, а размер файла - еще до начала, и подсчет будет мгновенным.
Имхо, считаю, что это не "крайний вариант", а самое верное решение. **Очень** большой файл будет даже без разбиения просто читаться слишком долго, и нужен фоновый поток.

Comment: Открыл первую попавшуюся книгу в формате txt. В книге довольно много мест, где в качестве строки может быть использован символ переноса. Большие количества страниц таким образом получаются. Мне предложили попробовать самостоятельно поразбивать текст на строки, при этом работать с файлом не как с текстом, а как с набором байт. Говорят, если курсором бегать по байтам, то получится очень быстро. Что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Неплохое предложение, но практического опыта такой реализации не имею, к сожалению. Могу только сказать относительно "если курсором бегать по байтам, то получится очень быстро": если узкое место - чтение файла, то да, в целом процесс будет быстрее. Но если узкое место - цикл разбиения, то быстрее не будет.

Comment: Узкое место - цикл разбиения по страницам. Чтож, все-таки попробую. Авось получится что-то из этого. Все-таки FBReader это достаточно быстро делает, и это просто не дает мне покоя )))

Comment: Ну тогда даже при быстром чтении файла все равно надо выносить разбиение в отдельный поток, верно же? :)

Comment: Строка `staticLayout.getLineCount();` лишняя, возвращаемый ею результат игнорируется.

Comment: Это уже остатки экс(кре)периментов, извиняюсь за лишний мусор

Comment: Пара замечаний по коду: `reader.read(char[] buffer)` не гарантирует полное заполнение массива, поэтому сохраняйте и используйте возвращаемое значение (количество реально прочитанных символов), иначе у вас при последнем чтении буфер будет содержать хвост от предпоследнего. `uncompletedtext` лучше сделать `StringBuilder`ом, вместо `substring` использовать `delete`.

Comment: Как ии предполагалось - данный вариант слишком медленный. Вся проблема кроется в преобразовании файла в массив chars и работа с этими chars. Плюс создание экземпляра `StaticLayout` очень громоздкая операция. Решил все перевести на работу с байтами а не с чарами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добиться "мгновенного" подсчета страниц и отображения нужной страницы не дожидаясь парсинга всего текста и не распараллеливания процесс.
Вот код, который отлично работает в одном потоке и обрабатывает 10 МБ текста примерно за пол секунды:

```
public void split(TextPaint textPaint, String filepath,Context context) {
        File file = new File(filepath);
        char[] bufferChar = new char[512];
        //How lines on page
        int maxLinesOnpage = 0;
        int symbolsOnLine = 0;
        StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(
                context.getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum),//short text with 100 lines (\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n)
                textPaint, //MONOSPACE!!!
                pageWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                lineSpacingMultiplier,
                lineSpacingExtra,
                false
        );
        int startLineTop = staticLayout.getLineTop(0);
        int endLine = staticLayout.getLineForVertical(startLineTop + pageHeight);
        int endLineBottom = staticLayout.getLineBottom(endLine);
        if (endLineBottom > startLineTop + pageHeight) {
            maxLinesOnpage = endLine - 1;
        } else {
            maxLinesOnpage = endLine;
        }
        symbolsOnLine = staticLayout.getLineEnd(0);

        try {
            RandomAccessFile rac = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int wordLen = 0; //Length of word in symbols
            int wordInBytes = 0; //Lenght of word
            int startLinePos = 0; //Start first line position
            int lineWidth = 0; //Current line length
            int totalLines =0; //Total lines on current page
            Log.e("Start pagination", "" + totalLines);
            long timeout= System.currentTimeMillis();
            int buflen=0; //Размер буффера
            int totalReadedBytes = 0; //Total bytes readed
            byte skipBytes = 0;
            while ( (buflen=rac.read(buffer))!=-1){
                for (int i=0;i<buflen;i++) {
                    totalReadedBytes++;
                    wordInBytes++;
                    if (skipBytes==0){ //Bytes on one symbol
                        if (unsignedToBytes(buffer[i])>=192){skipBytes=2;}
                        if (unsignedToBytes(buffer[i])>=224){skipBytes=3;}
                        if (unsignedToBytes(buffer[i])>=240){skipBytes=4;}
                        if (unsignedToBytes(buffer[i])>=248){skipBytes=5;}
                        if (unsignedToBytes(buffer[i])>=252){skipBytes=6;}
                    }
                    //Full bytes on symbol or not
                    if (skipBytes>0){
                        skipBytes--;
                        if (skipBytes>0){continue;}
                    }

                    if (buffer[i] == 13) {//We have a \r symbol. Ignore.
                        continue;
                    }



                    if (buffer[i]==10){//New line symbol
                        if (lineWidth + wordLen>symbolsOnLine){
                            totalLines++;
                            if (totalLines > maxLinesOnpage) {
                                int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes};
                                pages.add(pgsbytes);
                                startLinePos = totalReadedBytes ;
                                totalLines = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        wordLen=0;
                        wordInBytes=0;
                        totalLines++;
                        lineWidth=0;
                        if (totalLines>maxLinesOnpage){
                            int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes-1};
                            pages.add(pgsbytes);
                            startLinePos = totalReadedBytes-1;
                            totalLines=0;
                        }
                    }

                    if (buffer[i]==32){//Space symbol
                        if (lineWidth + wordLen+1<=symbolsOnLine){//Word fits in line
                            lineWidth+=wordLen + 1;
                            wordLen=0;
                            if (lineWidth==symbolsOnLine){
                                totalLines++;
                                if (totalLines > maxLinesOnpage) {
                                    int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes};
                                    pages.add(pgsbytes);
                                    startLinePos = totalReadedBytes ;
                                    totalLines = 0;
                                }
                                lineWidth = 0;
                                wordLen = 0;
                                wordInBytes=0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (lineWidth + wordLen==symbolsOnLine){
                                totalLines++;
                                if (totalLines > maxLinesOnpage) {
                                    int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes};
                                    pages.add(pgsbytes);
                                    startLinePos = totalReadedBytes ;
                                    totalLines = 0;
                                }
                                lineWidth = 0;
                                wordLen = 0;
                                wordInBytes=0;
                            } else {
                                totalLines++;
                                if (totalLines > maxLinesOnpage) {
                                    int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes - 1 - wordInBytes};
                                    pages.add(pgsbytes);
                                    startLinePos = totalReadedBytes - 1;
                                    totalLines = 0;
                                }
                                lineWidth = wordLen + 1;
                                wordLen = 0;
                                wordInBytes=0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (buffer[i]!=32&&buffer[i]!=10&&buffer[i]!=13){wordLen++; }
                    if (wordLen==symbolsOnLine){
                        totalLines++;
                        if (totalLines>maxLinesOnpage){
                            int[] pgsbytes = {startLinePos, totalReadedBytes-1  - wordInBytes};
                            pages.add(pgsbytes);
                            startLinePos = totalReadedBytes-1;
                            totalLines=0;
                        }
                        lineWidth=0;
                        wordLen=0;
                        wordInBytes=0;
                    }
                }

            }
            rac.close();
            timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeout;
            Log.e("TOTAL Time",  " time " + timeout + "ms");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("FILE READED FULLY!!", "READ COMPLETE!");
    }
```

Есть пока мелкие недочеты, которые необходимо решить, но все-таки он работает. Ну а текст нужной страницы можно получить например таким методом:

```
RandomAccessFile rac = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[pages.get(pagenum)[1] - pages.get(pagenum)[0]];
            rac.seek(pages.get(pagenum)[0]);
            rac.read(buffer);
            rac.close();
            return new String(buffer);
```

Надеюсь это решение поможет всем нуждающимся!

Comment: Шрифт отображения должен быть monospace, иначе нужно где-то определять размеры каждой буквы

Answer (score 2):

Параллельные задачи, типа

- "работа пользователя с уже прочитанными данными"
- "дочитывание файла"
- "доразбиение на страницы"
- "прослушивание входящих уведомлений о чем-нибудь"

должны выполняться в параллельных потоках: зачем пользователю ждать загрузки 500 страниц, чтобы прочитать только 5?
Поэтому правильным решением будет вынос разбиения в отдельный поток.
Для мгновенного подсчета числа страниц нужно размер файла разделить на примерное число байт на странице с округлением в большую сторону.